# How do I download the desktop version of Ubuntu 21.10 for ARM?

Tags: virtualization, arm

For Ubuntu 20.04, there is [this page](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/) which has links for Ubuntu desktop for both x86_64 (amd64) and ARM64. This installs fine, but I am having trouble installing libraries so I'm going to try another version.

For Ubuntu 21.10, I found [this page](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/21.10/release/) which has links for server images and a link for a Raspberry Pi version, but I am not using a Raspberry Pi and am looking for an ISO for installing on a general-purpose ARM device like with the 20.04 image.

For Ubuntu 22.04, I found [this page](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) with preview images but I am guessing that they are not very stable for general-purpose usage. It does look like what I'm looking for, but Parallels is not able to boot it.

Is there a way to download the desktop version of Ubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri for ARM?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no preinstalled desktop image for ARM machines other than a Raspberry Pi. You can either try the image for RPi in your generic ARM machine and hope that it would work, or, use the server image, and install a desktop environment with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` or `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop^` and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I would try the Pi image first as it's probably compatible with any ARM device.

Alternatively, after you install the server image, you can use the `tasksel` command to install the desktop environment.

##### Warning, NEVER use tasksel to remove packages. ONLY use tasksel to install packages!

The `tasksel` interface is very straight forward. Use the arrow keys and <kbd>space bar</kbd> to select items (**Ubuntu Desktop**) However, **do not install any of the ones listed as "live" desktops!** Then, use <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> to select OK, similar to legacy BIOS interface.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo tasksel
```

There are also a number of other groups of packages to install as well (media tools and other neat stuff).

---

Again, install the server first. After the installation, boot up the server use the `tasksel` command to install the desktop environment.

Additionally, if you get `command not found`, just install `tasksel`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

Comment: This method of installation is sometimes preferred because the server iso is smaller and faster to install. There's no GUI to slow down the installation.

Comment: Thank you, this works great! `tasksel` is a very nice tool. I got the live server install image for Ubuntu 21.10 for ARM, then installed it, then used `tasksel`, then rebooted and the GUI was immediately working. I was able to easily install Clang unlike with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: There is a bug in tasksel. NEVER remove packages using tasksel. Doing so may remove your entire system. Tasksel is completely safe to use to install packages but do NOT use tasksel to remove stuff.